# Simple Hangman game - first Python project

Tags: python, beginner, game, hangman

I created a basic Hangman game that uses a text file to select a secret word. Are there any areas for improvement?

```
import random


secret_word = ['']
user_list = []
number_of_tries = 5
guessed_letters = []
user_tries = 0
user_guess = ''


def select_word():
    global secret_word, user_list
    with open('secret_words.txt', 'r') as f:
        word = f.read()
        word_list = word.split('\n')
        secret_word = word_list[random.randint(1, len(word_list))]
        user_list = ['-'] * len(secret_word)


def game_over():
    if user_tries == number_of_tries or user_list == list(secret_word):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def user_input():
    global user_guess
    user_guess = input('Guess a letter\n')
    check_guess(user_guess)


def repeated(guess):
    global guessed_letters
    if guess in guessed_letters:
        print('You already guessed that letter!\n')
        return True
    else:
        guessed_letters.append(user_guess)
        return False


def check_guess(guess):
    correct_guess = False
    for x in range(len(secret_word)):
        if guess == secret_word[x]:
            user_list[x] = guess
            correct_guess = True
        elif not correct_guess and x == len(secret_word)-1:
            global user_tries
            user_tries += 1
            print('Wrong guess, you lose one try\n'
                  'Remaining tries : {}\n'.format(number_of_tries - user_tries))
    if correct_guess:
        print('Correct guess!')


def valid_input(user_letter):
    valid_letters = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
    if user_letter.lower() in list(valid_letters):
        return True
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
        return False

# main code:


print('----HANG MAN----')
print('*Welcome, guess the word\n*you have 5 tries.')
select_word()

while not game_over():
    for x in user_list:
        print(x, end='')
    user_guess = input('\nGuess a letter : ')
    if valid_input(user_guess):
        if repeated(user_guess):
            continue
        else:
            check_guess(user_guess)


if user_list != list(secret_word):
    print('Game over, you died!\ncorrect word was {}'.format(secret_word))
else:
    print('Congratulations! you guessed the correct word\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the word selection, there is a bug on

`secret_word = word_list[random.randint(1, len(word_list))]`

you should change to

`secret_word = word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list)-1)]`

because `random.randint(1, len(word_list))` does not return `0` index, and  could return an index off the bound (`len(word_list)`).

Also, you may remove `secret_word = ['']` and `user_list=[]` at the beginning.

```
number_of_tries = 5
guessed_letters = []
user_tries = 0
user_guess = ''

def select_word():
    with open('secret_words.txt', 'r') as f:
        word = f.read()
        word_list = word.split('\n')
        secret_word = word_list[random.randint(0, len(word_list)-1)]
        user_list = ['-'] * len(secret_word)
    return secret_word, user_list
```

looks more compact. So you can use it as :

```
print('----HANG MAN----')
print('*Welcome, guess the word\n*you have 5 tries.')

secret_word, user_list = select_word()

...
```

---

---

Also for efficiency and compactness, you can change this

```
while not game_over():
    for x in user_list:
        print(x, end='')
    user_guess = input('\nGuess a letter : ')
    if valid_input(user_guess):
        if repeated(user_guess):
            continue
        else:
            check_guess(user_guess)
```

to:

```
while not game_over():
    print(''.join(user_list))
    user_guess = input('\nGuess a letter : ')
    if valid_input(user_guess):
        if not repeated(user_guess):
            check_guess(user_guess)
```

---

---

For the game itself, you may want to try using classes, which will make it more readable and easier to analyze.

Comment: Thank you, I think you explained pjz suggestion of passing variables around instead of using global? will use that looks much better.

Comment: As pjz said : "put function results into variables and pass them around," is like what I did the `select_word` function..we can just move the global variables to become variables with values from results of the function

Answer (score 6):

- this if statement is a bit silly:

  ```
      if user_tries == number_of_tries or user_list == list(secret_word):
          return True
      else:
          return False
  ```

  It could easily be:

  ```
      return user_tries == number_of_tries or user_list == list(secret_word)
  ```

  since that expression evaluates to `True` or `False`, just return it directly
- Instead of

  ```
  secret_word = word_list[random.randint(1, len(word_list))]
  ```

  you can use the much more readable `random.choice`:

  ```
  secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
  ```
- your `user_input` routine isn't used at all.  Nuke it or use it.
- You use a lot of global state.  This is generally frowned upon because it makes the code less reusable.  You should first off, try to use less global state: put function results into variables and pass them around, instead.  This makes those functions much more reusable.  If you absolute *must* use global state, *still* don't: instead make an object that stores that "global" state, and turn the functions that use it into methods on the object.

Comment: Thank you for useful comment.
Can you explain more about passing variables around